# Warning: Significant figures with sigfig.py with a number with less significant figures

Tags: python, math, format, rounding

I'm making a program to solve linear equations by the Gauss Method using X significant figures.
My program uses the `round` function of sigfig.py to round to 3 significant figures every calculation

Not every number has 3 significant figures ("1" for example), so when I round "1" to 3 significant figures I get the next warning:

```
warning: %d significant figures requested from number with only %d significant figures
```

There is a way to avoid this warning or transform the number from 1 to 1.00 (3 significant figures)? This is how I use the function.

```
round(1, sigfigs=3)
```

The '1' and '3' are values that I get from the user input, so I can't fix the 1 with `format` because it should work for every number, even 0.000000365, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The warning still applies - your data doesn't become more significant by adding invented numbers. If you choose to ignore the warning, just add code that explicitly ignores the warning. It's a warning, not an error, after all - although you should think carefully before just getting it out of the way.

Of course, if your data somehow loses significant figures which it previously had, you shouldn't fix that in post - you should look at what's producing the data and fix problems there.